# Perform a function when a user clicks register button

Tags: wpdb

I am kind of new to WordPress coding. I'm trying to edit the wp-login.php file so if a user clicks the register button, it registers the user and stores the information in a different database table.

My code to insert new data into the database is below.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'wp_classes',
    array(
        'userlogin' => $user_id, 
        'classselect' => $_POST['class_select']
    )
);
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
```

**Update** - From what you said, I tried the code below, but no data was inserted into the database and no error.

```
add_action('user_register', 'store_class', 200);

function store_class($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_classes',
        array( 
            'userlogin' => $user_id, 
            'classselect' => $_POST['class_select']
        )
    );
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $wpdb->print_error();
}
```

Comment: How are you registering the user? Using default WordPress registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook your function with `user_register`. It will fire immediately after an user registration is done. And user id is passed to hook as an argument.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function ( $user_id  ) {
    //here goes your code
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but never got a my database inserted and no error, any other suggestions please?

Comment: Where did you write this code? It must be inside your `functions.php` file

Comment: works after putting the code inside functions.php file, for a reason i do not understand, since am new to wordpress code editing.... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your **functions.php** of your active theme or in your custom plugin.

```
<?php
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_insert_function' );

function my_insert_function ( $user_id  ) {
    //Write code to insert data in the seprate table 


}
?>
```

Before testing code directly, check by using **die();** in this function.